# load dynamically dll from file path at runtime in silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to figure out how you could go about .
how to load dynamically dll from file path at runtime in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to load the dll you can use the Load() of AssemblyPart

```
 AssemblyPart assemblyPart = new AssemblyPart();
 Assembly asm = assemblyPart.Load(dllStream);
```

and then create the instance with

```
asm.CreateInstance("...")
```